# Why do I get 'compute.images.get' permission error when cloning Google Compute instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-iam

I am working on a production web site on a Google Compute instance.

I want to set up a staging site, and read that the quickest way to do that is to clone the production instance.

When attempting to clone it, I get the error:

> Required 'compute.images.get' permission for 'projects/wordpress-sites-170807/global/images/SANITISED-template'

I've not been able to find any useful reference to `Required 'compute.images.get' permission` in any Google search.

**Questions:**

<strike>1. I only have Editor level permissions on this particular Cloud Platform console. Is this error specific to me as a user?</strike> *(I am now an "Owner" of the project, so we've eliminated the likelihood of my personal permissions being an issue)*

**2. If this permissions issue is related to the instance itself, how do I go about changing the permissions so that it has the "compute.image.get" permission?**

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/LP7Qrz1Fe44%5B1-25%5D), using the <s>clone button</s> "Create Similar" button copies the configuration to a new template. It does not make a new identical instance with the exact content of your persistent disk. In your case, the configuration included the source image from a different project. Thus, Compute Engine tried to access that project and since you have no access, it threw the error.

If the goal is to clone the instance including the persistent disk you need to create a new [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) or [image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#creating_a_custom_image) from the persistent disk, and then to retain other configs, you may use the clone button, but change the source image to the snapshot or image you have created earlier.

If the goal is creating a new instance from that original image in the other project, you need IAM roles in that project. For further information about the subject check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects#granting_a_user_access_to_images)

**UPDATE:**

The Google Cloud Console interface was updated several weeks ago, and the "CLONE" button was replaced by "CREATE SIMILAR".